# Remove duplicates on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to remove duplicates within a dataframe based on date, keeping the latest date and ensuring that the rows returned also take into account each value in Country. To illustrate with a sample df:

## Sample df

```
State   Country   Date          X1     X2     X3
A       AA        2021-01-01    8.0    5.0    0.0 
A       AA        2021-01-01    0.0    1.0    0.0
B       BB        2021-01-01    0.0    10.0   0.0 
X       XX        2021-01-01    0.0    0.0    0.0
```

## my code

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date'], keep = 'last')
df1
```

This gives me the output where only the last row, *Country(XX)* is returned. While this is correct, I would also like the code to take into account the Country column and give me instead the latest date for each country (i.e. the 2nd to 4th row). The output should also have the 'State' column as all '0' values.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Add country to your duplicates subset. So it bases the duplicates on country and date pairings not just the date by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `groupby` and `apply`

```
def fetch_latest_data(df):
    return df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date'], keep = 'last')
df  = df.groupby('Country').apply(fetch_latest_data).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Better option is to use `tail` -

```
df = df.groupby(['Country','Date']).tail(1)
```